# Simulating data generating process correctly

Tags: statistics, r, simulation

My aim is to simulate the following model by means of a Monte Carlo simulation. I wonder if my R code is correct for generating the data.

Could somebody check?

The model:

$$Y = \sum_{j=1}^{100} (1+(-1)^{j}A_j X_j + B_j \sin(6X_j)) \sum_{j=1}^{50} (1+X_j/50) + \epsilon$$

where

- \$A_1, \dots, A_{100}\$ are i.i.d. \$∼ \text{Unif}([0.6,1])\$
- \$B_1, \dots, B_{100}\$ are i.i.d. \$∼ \text{Unif}([0.8,1.2])\$ and independent of \$A_j\$
- \$X \sim \text{Unif}([0,1])\$ where all components are i.i.d. \$∼ \text{Unif}([0, 1])\$
- \$\epsilon \sim N(0,2)\$ and \$X_j\$ represents the \$j\$th column of the design matrix

You can find the model [here, p. 14](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/B_Yu/publication/243103448_Boosting_With_the_L_2_Loss/links/540c86ce0cf2f2b29a381fd5/Boosting-With-the-L-2-Loss.pdf)

This is my code attempt

```
n_sim <- 10
n_sample <- 200
n_reg <- 100
sd_eps <- sqrt(2)

X <- replicate(n_reg, runif(n_sample, 0,1))
A <- replicate(n_reg, runif(1, 0.6,1))
B <- replicate(n_reg, runif(1, 0.8,1.2))

f_1 <- vector(mode = 'integer', length = n_sample)
f_2 <- vector(mode = 'integer', length = n_sample)

for (d in seq(100)){
  part1 <- 1 + (-1)^d*A[d]*X[,d]+B[d]*sin(6*X[,d])
  f_1 <- f_1 + part1
}


for (d in seq(50)){
  part2 <- 1 + X[,d]/50
  f_2 <- f_2 + part2
}

# True DGP Train ----
f_true <- f_1*f_2
y <- replicate(n_sim, f_true) + replicate(n_sim, rnorm(n_sample, 0,sd_eps))
```

Comment: I find this model difficult to interpret. It seems ambiguous w.r.t. how many Y values are generated. Another question that came to mind w.r.t. interpreting the model is that the `X ~ Unif([0,1])` has an exponent of 100 in the PDF version of the model: `X ~ Unif([0,1]^100)`. I'm not familiar with that notation.

Comment: The `[0,1]^100` notation in `X ~ Unif([0, 1]^100)` is just shorthand for a setwise product. You'll probably have seen `R^3` as shorthand for the set of 3-dimensional real numbers. It means that `X` is a 100-dimensional vector where each component is uniformly distributed on the set `[0, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that jumps out from the definition is that, if you have X, A, B and epsilon, you can compute y deterministically. This means you can readily test your implementation. You should always strive to find ways to define pure functions in your R code, and try to use vectorisation instead of `for` loops.

Based on your existing code, I'll assume for a given model that X is a matrix (n_sample, 100), A and B are vectors of length 100 and epsilon is a vector of length n_sample.

Based on your implementation, the function would look something like

```
compute_y <- function(X, A, B, epsilon) {
  n_sample <- nrow(X)
  # note that your f_[1|2] stored `double`s not `integers`
  f_1 <- numeric(n_sample)
  f_2 <- numeric(n_sample)

  for (d in seq(100)){
    part1 <- 1 + (-1)^d*A[d]*X[,d] + B[d]*sin(6*X[,d])
    f_1 <- f_1 + part1
  }
  for (d in seq(50)){
    part2 <- 1 + X[,d]/50
    f_2 <- f_2 + part2
  }

  f_1 * f_2 + epsilon
}
```

But that's a bit scruffy.

The easiest bit to clean up is the bit that defines `f_2`:

```
f_2 <- numeric(n_sample)
for (d in seq(50)) {
    part2 <- 1 + X[,d]/50
    f_2 <- f_2 + part2
}
```

Here you're only using the first 50 columns of `X`. You could rewrite it as:

```
f_2 <- numeric(n_sample)
W <- 1 + X[, 1:50]/50
for (d in seq(50)) {
    f_2 <- f_2 + W[,d]
}
```

But in the latter, you're summing along the rows of `W`. So you could ditch the `for` loop altogether:

```
W <- 1 + X[, 1:50] / 50
f_2 <- rowSums(W)
```

This gives us:

```
compute_y <- function(X, A, B, epsilon) {
  n_sample <- nrow(X)

  f_1 <- numeric(n_sample)

  for (d in seq(100)){
    part1 <- 1 + (-1)^d*A[d]*X[,d] + B[d]*sin(6*X[,d])
    f_1 <- f_1 + part1
  }

  f_2 <- rowSums(1 + X[, 1:50] / 50)

  f_1 * f_2 + epsilon
}
```

There is a way to replace the for-loop that computes f_1.

First note you're adding 1 to f_1 one hundred times, so you might as well start with f_1 storing the value 100

```
f_1 <- rep(100, n_sample)

for (d in seq(100)){
  part1 <- (-1)^d*A[d]*X[,d] + B[d]*sin(6*X[,d])
  f_1 <- f_1 + part1
}
```

For speed, I'll just show you how to do it:

```
tX <- t(X)
a <- colSums(c(-1, 1) * A * tX)
b <- colSums(B * sin(6 * tX))
f_1 <- 100 + a + b
```

That code would be a bit faster, but I don't think it looks as clean as your definition of f_1.

If you want you can move the code that defines X, A, B, and epsilon into a model-definition function.